# encoding/decoding translated sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

I've the following script in my HTML:

```
jQuery.sundayMorning(text, { destination: 'en' }, function(response) {
    var uri = response.translation;
    var text = decodeURIComponent(uri);
    jQuery(".showText").val(text);
});
```

Example input in Spanish: `la casa de leo el combatiente`.

This translates into English as: `leo&#39;s house fighter`.

I want to show this as: `leo's house fighter`.

Anyone knows a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you would use the [`element.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function for this. But since you're using `val()`, you'll be trying to show it in an input element instead of some div. Input elements doesn't support the `html()` function. Since there's no direct API available in jQuery to decode HTML/XML entities, you'd like to create a div element, use its `html()` and then get the result as `text()`.

```
var decodedText = jQuery("<div/>").html(encodedText).text();
```

Then you can show this in the input element.

```
jQuery(".showText").val(decodedText);
```